# Как добавить дежурный класс через js на css при скроллинге

Tags: javascript, html, css

Например, я хочу что бы цвет окружности после прокрутки 50 пикселей поменял цвет, то есть просто добавил дежурный класс к основному.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('.ellipse').classList.add('active');
    }
});
```

```css
.ellipse{
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 512px;
    height: 512px;
    background: linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,0,185,1) 70%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 40px rgba(255,0,185,1);    
}

.ellipse.active{
    background: linear-gradient(255deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(232,255,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 40px rgba(232,255,0,1);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ellipse"></div>
```

Знаю что проблема в скрипте, пожалуйста помогите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, ты используешь метод dom-элемента на jquery-объекте, во-вторых, transition лучше ставить на сам элемент, а не на hover, ну а в-третьих, анимация градиента так работать не будет. Ниже исправленный код без анимации градиента.

Чтобы сделать анимацию графиента, надо использовать css houdini, подробнее в этом [ответе с кнопкой](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/952287/178988) - хром вроде уже поддерживает без флагов.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('.ellipse').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.ellipse {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  background: linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 185, 1) 70%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 40px rgba(255, 0, 185, 1);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.ellipse.active {
  background: linear-gradient(255deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(232, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 40px rgba(232, 255, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ellipse"></div>
```

Comment: Можете точно сказать куда нужно скопировать срипт точ то наверху ellipse

Comment: У вас на примере работает, у меня нет. То же самое написал. <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> вот это куда нужно скопировать. Обычно на самый конец body. Но страница грузится относительно долго + не работает

Answer (score 0):

Все смешалось – кони, люди.

У *Jquery* нет `classList`, но есть метод **[addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)**

```
$('.ellipse').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Этого недостаточно)